# Windows web server 2008, setting character encoding

Tags: windows-server-2008

How do you set the character encoding being used by the web server?

Thanks, R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found out what was causing the problem.  The style sheet had become corrupted with some eroneous characters being written to the front of the file.  The server was misinterpreting them causing it to change the encoding type that it was using.  Deleted these chars and it worked great.